# Exception While Creating Object in Java

Tags: java

why does the below code throws an Exception(java.lang.StackOverflowError)?

```
public class Test {
    Test f = new Test();


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test f = new Test();
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: StackOverflowError is not an Exception. and you should get this error because you have endless recursion.  What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Use a debugger to step through the code and the problem would be pretty obvious.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar If people started doing that 25% of the questions on this forum would answer themselves. ;)

Comment: @Peter then that's *definitely* behavior we want to encourage.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar Next people will be using profilers to solve CPU and memory problems. :O

Answer (score 6):

Each `Test` object creates a `Test` object which creates a `Test` object, ad nauseam.

Basically, your instance field `f` which has an initialization expression causes an infinite recursive loop that will pop the stack as the constructors are recursively invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Test objects refer to each other infinitely.  The way to solve this problem is to put main() outside class Test and delete the instance constructor of Test within class Test:

```
public class Test {
    //some code here
}

public class RunTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test f = new Test();
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
}
```

Also, it's best to name the class without main() something else because Test often refers to the class with main().

Comment: If no other code was changed moving the main method wouldn't change anything. Its the constructor thats at fault

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in StackOverflowError JavaDoc.

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses too deeply.

You are creating Test objects endlessly.